# Is it possible to configure a dependent library?

Tags: spring, maven, jpa, jpa-2.0, spring-jdbc

Seems I am cornered by this issue:

I have a maven project (project A) with spring3 framework, which is doing basic database accesses (CRUD) with JPA2.0 api, and this project will be packaged as a jar.

Now I need put this jar into another maven/spring based project (project B)'s dependency, and I am seeking that somehow if I can expose the datasource configuration of project A into project B, so I can change properties such as db connection string.

What's in my mind now is not a perfect solution, I explicitly imported project A's context.xml into project B's context.xml, but meanwhile I lose the flexibility described above.

Could someone advise if my original thought was possible and if yes, how to achieve? Thanks
 all!

Edit: our customer prefers not to change or change as less as I can to the source code of project A in terms of adding helper APIs that injects configurations into project B, but additional configuration files is ok.

Comment: Why not just expose an API in projectA that will take a DataSource as an argument?

Comment: since you have Spring already hanging around: use properties to do that. Spring has a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer that allows you to read some settings for your spring-context from external properties. Some random example: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/beans-spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/ - the spring manual has some stuff too. This way your jar can be "anonymous" and read the actual settings from its outside (project B in your case will provide a different set of settings).

Comment: hi @geoand thanks for the advice, but however project A didn't come with such kind of api and it should not be altered as possible as it can (according to customer requirement) - I updated the question

Comment: @JamesJiang I see. Does projectA set the data source on it's own? If so, how?

Comment: @geoand project A is a hub-like project that providing apis to external callers, so it will only 'use' project b for DAO actions but doesn't access database directly.

Comment: Yes but in order to provide the CRUD functionality it has to have some kind of configuration. What does that look like? It would help if you updated the question with some relevant code

Comment: @geoand briefly, project A provides an interface with a set of methods such as `connect()`, `lookup()`, `insert(E entity)` etc.. and project B implements the interface. I guess the thing A missed was that `connect()` doesn't have arguments defined, so it's hard to inject things like DataSource from there?

Comment: Yes it would seem that it's difficult to change things the way you want...